# pdf/javascript/html: pdf is damaged or incorrect file

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I want to save this html code to PDF:

```
<div id="mycontent">
    <h1>Sample PDF from HTML</h1>
    <p>This text you'll find in PDF page.</p>
</div>
```

Javascript I am using is:

```
const mycontent = document.getElementById('mycontent').outerHTML;

const blob = new Blob([mycontent], { type: 'application/pdf' });

const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'file.pdf';

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();

document.body.removeChild(link);
```

I can see the dialog to save and after save, I open the file to read it. I am getting this message:

**The content type is not valid to read the file or the file is damaged.**

What is wrong?

Comment: are you sure that by just giving the .pdf extension will automagically make some HTML markup — PDF? Have you tried a library instead? like html2pdf?

Comment: I am asking ... this code is openAI offered me

Comment: Well, avoid using A"I" for coding. Most of the time it provides junk information, the rest of the time it just hallucinates.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I disagree. I know that we shouldn't use it to write whole pieces of code, especially when you don't understand that, but AI can be ENORMOUSLY helpful in coding. I personally use it a lot to find bugs in my codes, do repetitive tasks or else help me in writing the styling for the HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a block of code to download

```
<div id="mycontent"><code>
%PDF-1.2
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Resources<</Font<</F4 4 0 R/F5 5 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Contents 6 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>>endobj
4 0 obj<</Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica-Bold/Subtype/Type1/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 32/LastChar 255>>endobj
5 0 obj<</Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica/Subtype/Type1/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 32/LastChar 255>>endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 310>>
stream
q .24 0 0 -.24 0 842 cm 116.6667 116.6667 2245.8336 3275.0003 re W* n q
/P <</MCID 0>> BDC 3.1250 0 0 3.1250 116.6667 116.6667 cm 0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG BT /F4 32 Tf 1 0 0 -1 8 37 Tm (Sample PDF from HTML) Tj EMC ET
/P <</MCID 1>> BDC BT /F5 16 Tf 1 0 0 -1 8 80 Tm (This text you'll find in PDF page) Tj EMC ET
Q
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000052 00000 n 
0000000101 00000 n 
0000000220 00000 n 
0000000337 00000 n 
0000000449 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
809
%%EOF
</code></div>
```

If you write it as a file (TEXT.PDF) and get all those decimal numbers correct it should work, as  intended after download so here:

[image]

Clearly this is a problematic method as that code bit&byte stream needs to be file name length handled with the correct "Decimal" memory file stream addresses. The simplest way arround that  is convert the "file BLOB" into a larger "data BLOB" then add that as a data:uri.

I have included that here but Web site security will usually not alow serving so right click and download should work. Or cut and paste the web page below into a html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0098)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207541/pdf-javascript-html-pdf-is-damaged-or-incorrect-file# -->
    <title>pdf/javascript/html: pdf is damaged or incorrect file - Stack Overflow</title>
<body>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207541/pdf-javascript-html-pdf-is-damaged-or-incorrect-file#"><span></span></a>
<iframe  src="data:application/pdf;base64,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"/></iframe>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You won't magically get a PDF just by saving some HTML text in a file with the extension `.pdf`.

You'll need a library like [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) or [html2pdf](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/) to layout the text on a page, then write it out as a PDF file – or, of course, you can [read the PDF specification and write a PDF-writing implementation yourself – it's just about 700 pages](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: this code is writen for openAI

Comment: @Dave ...what code?